# Is there a way in QGIS to cluster rather than overlap SVG icons from all layers

Tags: qgis, icon

I have many layers in QGIS containing points. All layers were added as delimited/csv.

**PROBLEM**: These are points from different layers, I'd like them clustered around the area instead:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming that this is what you want to achieve :

[image]

If the points are in separate layers, this doesn't seem to be possible.

However, **if the points are in the same layer :**

If they are in the same layer, you can **use the Point Displacement style**. This moves overlapping points onto a circle around them.

Since you want separate SVG icons for your originally separate layers, you may want to use a Rule-based rendering style with your Point Displacement :

1. Add a column to your layer, storing the original layer's name.
2. In the Point Displacement settings, choose "Rule-based" as your renderer.
3. Set your SVG file for each type of points, using the original layer name as a rule.

Point Displacement shows by default the circle where it puts the displaced points, and its center point. You can edit these out if you don't want them to be shown. (I personally edited those out by putting tiny values for their size/thickness, as just putting in "0" won't do.)