# Avoid overlap of SVG symbols in QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, symbology

I have a lot of Real Estate related data in QGIS, and I would like the ability to display the logos of nearby businesses on my QGIS maps for presentation purposes.

Currently, I have business locations marked as points and symbol rules for each company set up to display the .svg of their logo.

My problem is that I cannot find a way to separate them so that they do not overlap. I would ideally like them to adjust and add an arrow pointing to the actual point. Is there a way to do this?

[image: Overlapping Symbols]

Comment: possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278440/is-there-a-way-in-qgis-to-cluster-rather-than-overlap-svg-icons-from-all-layers/278465